# php5 + pdo + postgres + pgpool-ii: error without log

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, pgpool

I use pgpool-ii 3.2.1, php 5.3.3-7+squeeze14, postgresql 8.4.13.

I have some trouble with an insert query made by PDO, but I don't understand where the problem is because no log was written (postgres, apache2, pgpool-II).

The query is very simple, like

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, ...) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', ...)
```

if I disable pgpool-II (with PDO enabled) everything goes fine, even if I disable PDO, doing the query with `pg_query` (with pgpool-II turned on), the queries were executed correctly.
Other similar queries goes fine with PDO + pgpool-ii..anybody can help me?

Comment: Do you start a transaction before the INSERT but forgot to commit this transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your PDO Setting

```
setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

And if you call `beginTransaction();`, dont forget to call `commit();`

But actually, if you already set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to *TRUE*, you don't need to call `beginTransaction();` and `commit();`